# Django REST API refusing connection to browsers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I tried accessing my Django project fro another device, and it always returns either ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Chromium based browsers, or CORS on Firefox. I can access the API using Postman without issues. It also works if it is using localhost. Django serves HTML files no problem, just not the API calls. I've installed django-cors-headers and added it to installed applications, middleware, and allowed all.

Requests don't show on console either (using manage.py runserver).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Edit: I'm stupid.
The URL for fetch is pointing to local host instead of the server, so it's trying to access the API from the client...

Comment: Have you configured `ALLOWED_HOSTS` correctly?

Comment: I've allowed all for now using the " ['*'] " thing